# Train object detection model on Google Colab with TPU

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm training an object detection model by following the guide here https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-your-own-object-detector-ad69dda69c85

On Google Colab I am able to execute the following and it makes use of the GPU

```
python train.py --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_0.75_depth_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync.config
```

I would now like train by using the TPU but this obviously does not just work out of the box. Running train.py is slow and appears to be using CPU only. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

While using TPU in Google Colab, we should use the below mentioned code tocheck that the TPU devices are properly recognized in the environment:

```
import os
import pprint
import tensorflow as tf

if 'COLAB_TPU_ADDR' not in os.environ:
  print('ERROR: Not connected to a TPU runtime; please see the first cell in this notebook for instructions!')
else:
  tpu_address = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
  print ('TPU address is', tpu_address)

  with tf.Session(tpu_address) as session:
    devices = session.list_devices()

  print('TPU devices:')
  pprint.pprint(devices)
```

This should output a list of 8 TPU devices available in our Colab environment.

In order to run the `tf.keras` model on a TPU, we have to convert it to a `TPU-model` using the `tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu` module.

It can be done using the below code:

```
# This address identifies the TPU we'll use when configuring TensorFlow.
TPU_WORKER = 'grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR']
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

resnet_model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(
    resnet_model,
    strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
        tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_WORKER)))
```

Fore more information, please refer this [Medium Link](https://medium.com/@jannik.zuern/using-a-tpu-in-google-colab-54257328d7da) and [this Link](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/step-by-step-use-of-google-colab-free-tpu-75f8629492b3).